# CSS keyframes animation not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-animations, keyframe

I have made an animation for some elements (images and buttons) to fade in and out using opacity. It works perfectly on all browsers, except on Safari. When I try to run it in Safari, all my elements has 100% opacity without any animation to see..

Example from the button element:

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div id = "ctaButton" class="animate-fadeButton">
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```css
    #ctaButton{
        position:absolute;
        margin: auto;
        left: 26%;
        top:70%;
        padding:10px;  background: #CCC;
        background-color: rgba(255,131,15,0.5);

    }

@keyframes fadeButton {
      0%   { opacity:0; }
      25%   { opacity:0; }
      35%  { opacity:1; }
      90% { opacity:1; }
      100% { opacity:0; }
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    @-o-keyframes fadeButton{
      0%   { opacity:0; }
      25%   { opacity:0; }
      35%  { opacity:1; }
      90% { opacity:1; }
      100% { opacity:0; }
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes fadeButton{
      0%   { opacity:0; }
      25%   { opacity:0; }
      35%  { opacity:1; }
      90% { opacity:1; }
      100% { opacity:0; }
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeButton{
      0%   { opacity:0; }
      25%   { opacity:0; }
      35%  { opacity:1; }
      90% { opacity:1; }
      100% { opacity:0; }
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    .animate-fadeButton {
       -webkit-animation: fadeButton 15s infinite;
       -moz-animation: fadeButton 15s infinite;
       -o-animation: fadeButton 15s infinite;
        animation: fadeButton 15s infinite; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the animation name and timing before the keyframes animation and not after

**CSS**

```
#ctaButton {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 26%;
  top: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #CCC;
  background-color: rgba(255, 131, 15, 0.5);
}

.animate-fadeButton {
  -webkit-animation: fadeButton 15s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeButton 15s infinite;
  -o-animation: fadeButton 15s infinite;
  animation: fadeButton 15s infinite;
}

@keyframes fadeButton {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-o-keyframes fadeButton {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeButton {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeButton {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Comment: This solved it!

Thank you so much. Can't believe i've been pulling my hair over a problem with such a simple solution..!